# Estimated shipping not showing in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to show the Estimated Shipping and Tax block on Magento 2 but it's not showing up. I found multiple ways to remove it but I can't figure out how to show one. Previous developer left the project hanging and I am trying to get this fixed. Upon inspecting the page, I found that it has the following elements

```
<div id="block-summary" data-bind="scope:'block-summary'" class="content" data-role="content" aria-labelledby="block-shipping-heading" style="display: none" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">
```

And shipping.phtml has the following

```
<div id="block-summary" data-bind="scope:'block-summary'" class="content" data-role="content" aria-labelledby="block-shipping-heading">
```

If I remove "display: none" using Chrome developer tools, I am able to see the block but I can't figure out how to make this change permanent. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I added `display: block !important` in shipping.phtml and that fixed the issue.